# Limitar la creación de usuario en firebase

Tags: firebase, login

Estaba realizando un login para una web utilizando Firebase Authentication, este login sería para acceder al apartado de administración de una web, estoy utilizando la autenticación por email y contraseña, pero me gustaría que solo se pudiese crear un usuario, puesto que cualquiera con el método `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` y los parámetros de configuración podría crear un nuevo usuario y acceder al apartado de configuración.

Si esto no es posible, ¿me podrían aconsejar otro sistema?

Comment: Porque querrías publicar el método si solo vas a usar un usuario. Creá el usuario y no expongas el método.

Comment: Tal vez podés aclarar un poco más, en qué condiciones necesita que `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` esté disponible.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no se puede limitar el número de usuarios, pero podrías limitar accesos de lectura y escritura a un solo usuario en la configuración de reglas de seguridad de la base de datos.

En adición podría sugerir que si solo necesitas un usuario no publiques el método `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`

Comment: Hola Daniel. mi base de datos no la almacenaría en firebase, de firebase solo me gustaría utilizar el apartado de autenticación. Con respecto a lo de no publicar el método, ese método es público y es fácil encontrarlo en la red.